# What is String or where does this come from?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While trying to understand d3 I saw the line `.text(String);`. I could not understand what String is suppose to be. I thought maybe its an empty string (nope), a method (i didnt see that in the api reference) and pondered what else it could be.

I commented it out below and got expected results. What I don't understand is what is String and why does it work. With this line my 3 squared boxes has text (its a internal value of the data it will represent later) while commented out it does not.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qBcD2/1/)

Html

```
<div class='chart' id='chart-10'/>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
    var w = 360;
    var h = 180;
  var svg = d3.select("#chart-10").append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

  var g = svg.selectAll(".data")
      .data([50,150,250])
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "data")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + 20 * (i + 1) + ",20)"; });

  g.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "little")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  g.append("rect")
      .attr("x", -10)
      .attr("y", -10)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .style("fill", "lightgreen")
      .style("stroke", "green");

  g.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
;//      .text(String);


    g.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + 20 * (i + 1) + ",20)"; });
    g.select("rect").style("opacity", 1);
    g.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

    var t = g.transition().duration(750);
    t.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + d + ",90)"; });
    t.select("circle").attr("r", Math.sqrt);
    t.select("rect").style("opacity", 1e-6);
```

Comment: Looks like d3 accepts a function that takes data as parameter: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/using-your-data/. Here, the data is converted into a string with `String`.

Comment: @pimvdb: I still have no idea what its suppose to be. Is that a global func? var? Also your link doesnt actually use `String`...

Comment: Yes, `String` is a global function that returns the first argument as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [`String` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). According to [d3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-text), as pointed out by Matt:

> if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum `d` and the current index `i`, with the this context as the current DOM element. The function's return value is then used to set each element's text content.

So, you set `g.data` to `[50,150,250]` a few lines before. Each number is converted to a String object by the `String` constructor, returned and used as the text values of your DOM nodes.

Comment: I think it does make sense... the [docs say](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-text) " if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum d..." Calling `String(datum)` will coerce it into a string, which is what the text will be set to.

Comment: @Matt that still doesnt help. I'm passing in String, its not like i am writing &String (c++) or `out String` (C#).

Comment: @user1955298: It does help. We don't have `&` as the reference operator in JavaScript or any `out` rubbish; we just pass the object directly.

Comment: @Matt: I named myself so you can @ me better. I still don't understand. Aren't I passing in undefined? IIRC changing a var passed into a function doesnt change it outside. Changing an object member however is different as it isnt the actual variable itself

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. It is being converted to a string? Where is it being returned too?

Comment: @BruteCode: You're passing the *function* `String`. Try `String(4)`, `String([1,2,3])` and `String("hi")` on your console to see the behavior; it takes the first argument, and returns it as a string (basically by calling `.toString()` on it).

Comment: @BruteCode: So passing this function tells d3 (per the spec as bfavaretto includes in his answer) to set the `textContent` property for each of your elements to the result of calling `String()`, passing the datum as the parameter. Passing a number to `String()` will return that number, as a string, which is what you're seeing as the `textContent`

Comment: @Matt: Oh! Alright. I'll accept that as an answer if you write it

Comment: @BruteCode: Meh, it's exactly what bfavaretto has in this answer just in a different way. I'll leave my comments here for the alternative explanation, but feel free to give bfavaretto the tick; I'm in a rush!